# How to get scheduled refresh in powerbi service to work where one connection is a sharepoint online list and one is local excel file

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am able to setup the scheduled refresh when I drop the local connection to the Excel file and only keep the SharePoint online connection. When I add back the connection of the local Excel file the scheduled refresh feature in powerbi service is grayed out. Is there a way to only refresh the SharePoint online connection while the 2nd connection (to local Excel) is kept in the pbix file?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is it just that the schedule refresh feature is disabled?

Comment: @B.Griffin It was just disabled. I found a workaround: The files were in one drive already and I created a web connection to the one drive address to the Excel file. Then I returned to the settings in Powerbi service and had to update the data source credentials. Then scheduled refresh wasn't disabled anymore.